# Writing to a text file from python list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a text file and write to it from a python list.

Code:

```
file1 = open("test.txt","w")
test_list = ['hi', 'hello', 'welcome']
for each_ele in test_list:
    file1.write(each_ele+'\n')
file1.close()
```

Still the file is empty, any suggestions please?

Comment: `print(test_list)` shows what?

Comment: What is `test_list`?

Comment: Are you sure that `len(test_list) > 0`?

Comment: I have updated the test_list. It is just a list of strings.

Comment: Cannot reproduce the problem. Check if you have write access to the target file/directory.

Comment: you are doing everything right. Check if you are opening correct file when you check for result

Comment: Your code works. Maybe you are lookin in the wrong directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is recommended to use `with` when operating with files. This works:

```
test_list = ['a', 'b']
with open("test.txt","w") as file1:
    for each_ele in test_list:
        file1.write(each_ele+'\n')
```

Most likely `test_list` is empty in your case... Or you are looking in a wrong directory for the file...

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are looking at the right file, Use:

```
import os
os.getcwd()
```

to check for your working directory, your created file should be there.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me, I believe the py file doesn't have required permission,
change the owner of the file using `chown user:user filename.py` and 
try:

file1 = open("sampletest.txt","`w+`")

```
file1 = open("sampletest.txt","w+")
test_list = ['hi', 'hello', 'welcome']
for each_ele in test_list:
    file1.write(each_ele+'\n')
file1.close()
```

output :

hi
hello
welcome